# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Help

When I am developing locally my Asp.Net MVC web application I get the following error message in the console.

> api.webtest.net/webspeeds:1 Failed to load resource:
>   net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

My asp.net application runs fine - except for this annoying message being printed. It occurs when I am working offline (no internet connect).

Why is my asp.net app trying to connect to the internet - all my service calls are local - no need for an internet connection:

Comment: It clearly says you are offline, which means you are not on the same network with the api you are trying to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it’s a browser extension?

Probably [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speedtest-by-ookla/pgjjikdiikihdfpoppgaidccahalehjh?hl=en)

Try to run in other browser or add this to *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts*

```
127.0.0.1 api.webtest.net
```

Comment: Thank you, that extension was the culprit!

Comment: Glad to have been of help